# What is wrong with Ubuntu 16.04 and libsqlite3?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, sqlite

Given this minimal c file to test sqlite3.

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion()); 

    return 0;
}
```

On a blank new Ubuntu 16.04 (@ digitalocean) I do:

```
$ apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev build-essential



$ gcc -lsqlite3 s.c
/tmp/cc7BAtF8.o: In function `main':
s.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `sqlite3_libversion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On a blank new debian 8 it works like a charm

```
$ apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev build-essential
$ gcc -lsqlite3 s.c 
$ ./a.out 
3.8.7.1
```

I don't see why it is failing. Even compiling sqlite3 by my self doesn't help on ubuntu. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
using tcc or clang works on the ubuntu machine. it seems that only gcc is affected.

here is the verbose output of gcc

```
$ gcc -v -lsqlite3 s.c 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu s.c -quiet -dumpbase s.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase s -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/cc7Euj15.s
GNU C11 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: eb080614e8c0415bfb1aad7fb88ffefc
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccPr0Br4.o /tmp/cc7Euj15.s
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccRCeMS2.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. -lsqlite3 /tmp/ccPr0Br4.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/ccPr0Br4.o: In function `main':
s.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `sqlite3_libversion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Which version of the SQLite library does that machine have?

Comment: @KenWhite Not a duplicate: poster is linking with the correct library.

Comment: @CL. the ubuntu machine has 3.14.2. the debian (as pasted above) 3.8.7.1

Answer (score 0):

While using `gcc`, symbols are referenced in the order they are given on the command line.

so `gcc -lsqlite3 s.c` does not work. but `gcc s.c -lsqlite3` works fine.

For `tcc` and `clang` the order does not seem to be of interest.